# How could flink pass environment variable to job or cluster?

Tags: apache-flink

For example in Spark we could set environment variable to executor job-wisely by

```
spark.executorEnv.VAR=xxx
```

Is it possible in flink? If could not set by job, set by cluster is also accepted.

I even tried set the variable by `export VAR=xxx` in `$FLINK_HOME/bin/config.sh` and restart cluster, but still not work, seems only work in master node task manager(I set master node also as a task manager), the other task managers did not use the set variables.

**Noted that this is question about system environment variables like `$PATH`, not JVM options**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways to provide the env variable is via `env.java.opts` config property in `flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml` configuration file like

```yaml
env.java.opts: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
```

This provides the java options to start the JVM of all Flink processes with.
See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#jvm-and-logging-options for details.

Also, I haven't tried it on my own, but seems that it's possible to forward custom job manager / task manager environment variables as well via `containerized.master.env.` and `containerized.taskmanager.env.` configuration properties: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#forwarding-environment-variables :

- `containerized.master.env.`: Prefix for passing custom environment variables to Flink’s JobManager process. For example for passing LD_LIBRARY_PATH as an env variable to the JobManager, set `containerized.master.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH`: “/usr/lib/native” in the flink-conf.yaml.
- `containerized.taskmanager.env.`: Similar to the above, this configuration prefix allows setting custom environment variables for the workers (TaskManagers).

Comment: This is java opt for JVM, what about environment variables?

Comment: Could you please clarify your use case ? java opts can also be read from the application via `System.getProperty`

Comment: @Litchy I have updated the answer with the properties setting JobManager/TaskManager environment variables as well.

Comment: Thanks, I see the guide. However it seems only on Yarn where these env var could be exported. So technically Flink does not have this function, just like python env could only be packed through Spark Yarn but not Spark Standalone?

Comment: Yes, these configs are taken into account only in containerized cluster setup - yarn, mesos, kubernetes. Standalone setup does not provide such facility.

Comment: Just discussion, Spark Standalone provide this facility, how they did it?

Comment: They parse the CLI parameter `spark.executor.memory` and then take this into account when crating `SparkContext` and later on start executors: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a8b568800e64f6a163da28e5e53441f84355df14/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2850

Comment: Trying to set it up using `containerized.master.env` and `containerized.taskmanager.env`. Job manager UI show it as `containerized.taskmanager.env.SERVICE_NAME`. But there is still error in task manager logs as `The system environment SERVICE_NAME is missing`. Any pointer ? here is the code `private String serviceName = System.getenv("SERVICE_NAME");`

Comment: How to setup yarn master application environment?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i needed to pass custom ENV.

My var was `REDIS_URL`. Pass the value using:

```
env.java.opts: -DREDIS_URL=localhost
```

in `flink-conf.yaml`.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour).

Comment: You are setting environment variable via java opt, I do not think it could work? Are you setting just localhost, or other non-default config.